# Why component is not refreshing in react hooks?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I tried to dispatch the API call using redux in useEffect hooks. After the response came to redux-saga response goes to reducer and the reducer updated the state successfully but my component is not refreshing.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import SubscriptionComponent from '../../Components/Subscription/Subscription';
import SubscriptionActions from '../../Redux/Subscription/Actions';
import {
  getMySubscriptions,
  getMySubscriptionByName,
  getMySubscriptionByGroup,
} from '../../Redux/Subscription/Selectors';

const Subscription = (props) => {
  const { navigation } = { ...props };
  const [visible, setVisible] = useState(false);
  const subscriptionList = useSelector((state) => getMySubscriptions(state));
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const [data, setData] = useState(subscriptionList);
  const payload = {
    memberId: '604f2ad047bc495a0a7fad26',
    vendorId: '5fd484c39590020dc0dfb82a',
    vendorOrgId: '5fd484439590020dc0dfb829',
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(SubscriptionActions.fetchMySubscriptions(payload));
  }, [data]);

  const onHandleSubscriptionByName = () => {
    setVisible(false);
    const subscription = getMySubscriptionByName(data);
    setData(subscription);
  };
  const onHandleSubscriptionByGroup = () => {
    setVisible(false);
    const subscription = getMySubscriptionByGroup(data);
    setData(subscription);
  };
  return (
    <SubscriptionComponent
      list={data}
      navigation={navigation}
      onPressList={(val) =>
        navigation.navigate('SubscriptionDetails', { _id: val._id, name: val.name })
      }
      visible={visible}
      openMenu={() => setVisible(!visible)}
      closeMenu={() => setVisible(!visible)}
      sortByName={() => onHandleSubscriptionByName()}
      sortBySub={() => onHandleSubscriptionByGroup()}
    />
  );
};

export default Subscription;
```

used reselect to get the state from redux.

```
export const getMySubscriptions = createSelector(mySubscriptionSelector, (x) => {
  const mySubscriptions = x.map((item) => {
    return {
      _id: item._id,
      image: 'item.image,
      description: item.description,
      name: item.name,
      subscriptionGroup: item.subscriptionGroup,
      subscriptionAmount: item.subscriptionAmount,
      status: item.status,
      delivery: item.delivery,
      product: item.product,
    };
  });
  return mySubscriptions ;
});
```

Why component is not refreshing.

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're storing the selection result in local state.

```
const subscriptionList = useSelector((state) => getMySubscriptions(state));
const [data, setData] = useState(subscriptionList);
```

`useState(subscriptionList)` will only set `data` initially not on every update.

EDIT:
Your setup is a little odd:

```
useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(SubscriptionActions.fetchMySubscriptions(payload));
  }, [data]);
```

Using `data` in the dependency array of `useEffect`, will cause refetching the data, whenever `data` is updated. Why? I looks like your sorting is working locally, so no need to refetch?

I would suggest to store the sort criteria (byName, byGroup) also in Redux and eliminate local component state, like that:

```
// ToDo: rewrite getMySubscriptions so that it considers sortCriteria from Redux State
const subscriptionList = useSelector(getMySubscriptions);
const dispatch = useDispatch();

};
useEffect(() => {
  dispatch(SubscriptionActions.fetchMySubscriptions(payload));
// Empty dependency array, so we're only fetching data once when component is mounted
}, []);

const onHandleSubscriptionByName = () => {
  dispatch(SubscriptionActions.setSortCriteria('byName'));
};

const onHandleSubscriptionByGroup = () => {
  dispatch(SubscriptionActions.setSortCriteria('byGroup'));
};
```

As mentioned in the comments you will need to add a new action `setSortCriteria` and reducer to handle the sorting and adjust your selector, so that it filters the subscription list when a sortCriteria is active.

Comment: yes, The problem data is not updating subscriptionList after reducer got the response

Comment: I added a suggestion how to improve your solution

Comment: this is not problem with sort function if I remove the sort function the problem is remains same

Comment: As I said (one of) your problem(s) is, that you pass `data` to your `SubscriptionComponent` instead of `subscriptionList`. Try passing `subscriptionList` directly and I'm sure it will work, but then sorting will be broken. Then my suggestion kicks in ;)

Answer (score 0):

You do not update data after fetching new subscription.

```
const [data, setData] = useState(subscriptionList);
```

Only initializes data, but does not update it, you need to add useEffect to update data:

```
useEffect(() => {
  setData(subscriptionList);
}, [JSON.stringify(subscriptionList)]);
```

`JSON.stringify` only used for deep compare complex objects, since useEffect only runs shallow compare and might miss, changes in objects.

-----EDIT------

Other problem might be that your `getMySubscriptions` function might need deep compare, since useSelector by itself doesn't do that, example might be:

```
import { useSelector, shallowEqual } from 'react-redux';

const subscriptionList = useSelector((state) => getMySubscriptions(state), shallowEqual);
```

*Note that both solutions must be used.*

Comment: @AsZik Updated my answer with other possible problem, if this does not work, please post your `getMySubscription` function.

Comment: have you tried adding `shallowEqual` to `useSelector`?

Comment: It's proabbably what's causing to return cached values, you can read more on equality check of useSelector here: https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks#equality-comparisons-and-updates